# Which page can I find the definition of $\mathcal O_S$-algebra in "Stacks Project"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $(S,\mathcal O_S)$ be a scheme. Which page can I find the definition of $\mathcal O_S$-algebra in "Stacks Project"?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Stacks Project, but you'll surely find this in any book on scheme theory. It should be a sheaf of rings together with an $\mathcal{O}_S$-module structure in a compatible way. It might be a worthwhile exercise to figure out what 'in a compatible way' should mean.

Comment: @SofieVerbeek For instance, can you tell me which page I can find the definition of $\mathcal O_S$-algebra in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry"?

Comment: You'll find the definition of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules in Section 2.5. An explicit exercise mentioning $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras is Exercise 2.5.17 (c), though he does not give more details regarding the definition than my comment.